# How to check if there is a specific text inside a cell in excel

Tags: excel

is there anyway to check if there is an existing text in excel?

For example:
COLUMN A1 - "CONSTRUCTION -RP"
COLUMN B1 - "AM"

I need to check if COLUMN A1 has no "OMA" on it.
In terms:

IF (A1 has "OMA" AND B1 is "AM" OR A1 has no OMA)
THEN FORMULA HERE
ELSE IF (A1 has "OMA" AND B1 IS NOT "AM")
THEN FORMULA HERE

Answer (score 0):

Here's a formula that might be of help to you.

`=IF(A1="OMA", IF(B1="AM",1+1,2+2), 3+3)`

Essentially 1+1, 2+2, and 3+3 would be replaced with the formulas you have if logical test 1 = true, logical test 2 = true, or if neither test held true.

If you have any questions about this just ask below.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ISNUMBER(SEARCH())`

```
=IF(OR(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("OMA",A1)),B1="AM"),ISERROR(SEARCH("OMA",A1))),yourformula,yourotherformula)
```

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(OR(AND(ISNUMBER(FIND("OMA",A1)),B1="AM"),ISERROR(FIND("OMA",A1))),1,0)`

Replace the 1 and 0 with your formula if true and formula if false. In english this formula does is if either (OMA is in a1 and b1=AM) or (OMA is not in a1), then true, otherwise false

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work since when i tried changing my B1 to PM it outputs 1

=IF(OR(AND(ISNUMBER(FIND("OMA",A1)),B1="AM"),ISERROR(FIND("OMA",A1))),"OMA & AM OR NOT OMA", "OMA ONLY")

Comment: How I have it set up if A1 doesn't have "OMA" then it will output 1 no matter what b1 is. If this is not how you want it to work, please read thorugh my "in english" above and clarify what your desired result is.